# Hatching turtle of specified color based on other turtle color

Tags: netlogo

I want to hatch a turtle after two different colors of turtles overlap.

```
    to interact
  if any? other turtles-here
   [
    birth
   ]
   ;detect interaction
  end

to birth
  ask turtles
    [ 
     hatch random 5 [ fd 1 ] 
    ]
end
```

I would like to hatch a turtle that was an average color of the two parent turtles that interacted.

something like.

```
 to birth
  ask turtles
    [ hatch random 5 
[ let color be sum of previous turtles color sum  / 2
 fd 1 ] ]
end
```

also any tips on what I might be misunderstanding about netlogo syntax might be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but if the parents are the only ones on that patch when they give birth then this block should do the trick.

```
to birth
  let Q mean [color] of turtles-here  

  ask one-of turtles-here
   [hatch random 5 
     [
      set color Q
      fd 1 
     ]
   ] 
end
```

I'm not sure if you'd need to make the offspring it's own breed though to tell them to change their color and move, or if this will work... If this doesn't work then:

```
breed[offsprings offspring]
breed[parents parent]

to birth
  let Q mean [color] of parents-here  

  ask one-of parents-here
   [hatch-offsprings random 5 ]

  ask offsprings-here
     [
      set color Q
      fd 1 
     ]

end
```